# Linuxのi686-w64-mingw32向けにOpenSSLライブラリを使った開発環境を構築する方法

Tags: openssl

タイトルのようにしたいのですがうまくいきません。

環境はubuntu 16.04 LTSです。

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
その場で解凍、OpenSSLのディレクトリを開く
./config --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32
make
make test
sudo make install

このサイトのサンプルコードを使って
http://a4dosanddos.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/01/191730

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 tes.c
すると下のエラーが出ます。

```
/tmp/ccozGj6U.o:tes.c:(.text+0x24): `MD5_Init' に対する定義されていない参照です
/tmp/ccozGj6U.o:tes.c:(.text+0x77): `MD5_Update' に対する定義されていない参照です
/tmp/ccozGj6U.o:tes.c:(.text+0xb4): `MD5_Final' に対する定義されていない参照です
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

どうすればいいと思いますか？

追記：

```
making depend in crypto...
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/[username]/openssl-1.0.2h/crypto' に入ります
../util/domd: 31: ../util/domd: makedepend: not found
mv: cannot stat 'Makefile.new': No such file or directory
Makefile:136: ターゲット 'local_depend' のレシピで失敗しました
make[1]: *** [local_depend] エラー 127
make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/[username]/openssl-1.0.2h/crypto' から出ます
Makefile:471: ターゲット 'depend' のレシピで失敗しました
make: *** [depend] エラー 1
```

Comment: しなくても良い遠回りをしているように見えます。
クロスコンパイルなんて難しいことをする前に基本を理解した方が良いと思います。
①[参考サイトの通り](http://a4dosanddos.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/01/191730)にコンパイルしない（cryptoをリンクしていない）。
②エラーの意味を理解しようとしない（[以前にも同様の質問あり](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/19072/7291)）。
③一般的なコンパイラーを使わない（[以前にも同様の指摘あり](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/19073/7291)）。

Comment: ①参考サイトのコンパイラはmingwではなく通常のgccを使っていて、mingwにも使える情報なのかがわからなかったので、ソースコードをコピーしただけで読んでいません。②エラーの意味を理解しようとしたり検索したりした結果解決出来なかったので質問しました。以前の質問とは環境が違います。③VisualStudioでの環境構築はあの後成功しました。それからmingwを使った環境を構築したいと思い、調べているところです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらの環境も `Ubuntu 16.04` ですが、以下の様にして `libcrypto` を作成しました。

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 \
    perl Configure mingw no-shared no-asm --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32
$ make depend
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

`Configure` を実行する際に環境変数 `CC` を設定して、オプションに `no-asm` を指定する必要があります。

インストール後、サンプルプログラムをコンパイルして Windows 環境で実行してみました。

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 tes.c -lcrypto -o tes.exe

## 実行形式ファイルを Windows 環境へコピーして実行
C:\> tes
md5 digest: ea703e7aa1efda0064eaa507d9e8ab7e
```

**追記**

> ```
> making depend in crypto...
> make[1]: ディレクトリ '/home/[username]/openssl-1.0.2h/crypto' に入ります
> ../util/domd: 31: ../util/domd: makedepend: not found
> ```

`makedepend` コマンドがインストールされていませんので、`xutils-dev` パッケージをインストールして下さい。

```
$ sudo apt-get install xutils-dev
```

Comment: make dependでエラーが出ました。エラー内容を追記しました。

Comment: OpenSSLライブラリが使えるようになりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

コンパイルのオプションに「-lcrypto」が必要ではないでしょうか。

Comment: -lcryptoも必要でした。ありがとうございます。